# Kubernetes Pod receiving curl requests when restarting from deletion, with replicated pod alive

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a deployment with 2 replicated pods.
These pods are using an internal clusterIP.

I have a dummy pod, running a script making curl requests to a service hosted on these pods.
When I delete one of these pods, half of the requests are still being sent to the pod restarting. So the requests are unsuccessful. I expected kubernetes to transfer all this traffic to the running pod.

edit: My requests are targeting the service NOT the individual pods

How can I implement this expected behavior?

I am using EKS

Comment: Are you using Pod's IPs directly with cURL? If so, then You should use K8s' `Service` to send HTTP requests instead. K8s `Service` will ensure that your HTTP requests are going to the running Pods only.

Comment: @TAM Yes I am targeting my service, not pod ip

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by implementing readiness and liveness probes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).